# Why does the Category Theory Definition of $\mathbf{Set}$ Product Not Define a Subset of a Product?

Tags: category-theory

#### 1 Definition of Product

From [the Wikipedia Definition of a Categorical Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(category_theory)) (in the simple binary case):

[image]

#### 2 Question

Now let us focus our attention on $\mathbf{Set}$.

$$
Y = \{1, 2 \} \\
X_1 = \{a, b \} \\
X_2 = \{c, d \} \\
$$

Then if $1 \mapsto a, c$ and $2 \mapsto b, d$ (under each respective $f_1$ and $f_2$), then wouldn't we have that $Y$ maps to $\{ (a, c), (b, d) \}$ rather than the full $X_1 \times X_2$?

If that's the case, then how does the Categorical Definition of a product square with the Set Theory definition (in the $\mathbf{Set}$)?

Comment: The universal property says nothing about $f$ being surjective (or an epimorphism), and in fact you gave an example where it isn't.  That doesn't prevent $f$ from being a morphism with its designated codomain being $X_1 \times X_2$.

Comment: Also, the object called $X$ or $X_1 \times X_2$ has to be *fixed* along with $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$, but that single fixed $X, \pi_1, \pi_2$ has to work for *all possible* $Y, f_1, f_2$.  So, in your example, $\{(a,c), (b,d)\}$ happens to work for those maps.  However, if you use the same $Y$, but maps $1 \mapsto a, d$, $2 \mapsto b, c$, there is no way to define $f : Y \to \{(a,c), (b,d)\}$ satisfying the conditions.

Comment: @DanielSchepler: Your second comment cleared up the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

When we write $h : A \to B$, we mean that $B$ is the *codomain* of $h$. We don't mean that $h$ is the *image* of $h$.

In your example, the constructed map $f$ has *codomain* $\{ (a,c), (a,d), (b,c), (b,d) \}$. Your observation, however, is that $f$ has *image* $\{ (a, c), (b,d)\}$. There's no reason to require these two sets be equal — a priori, all you can say is that the image is a subset of the codomain.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not being precise enough with the crucial question:

> wouldn't we have that $Y$ maps to $\{ (a, c), (b, d) \}$

Well, certainly there does *exist* a function $g:Y\to \{(a,c),(b,d)\}$ such that $g(1)=(a,c)$ and $g(2)=(b,d)$. But this $g$ is not the product of $f_1$ and $f_2$, precisely because of the definition of a product: the codomain of $g$ is not (the Cartesian product of sets) $X_1\times X_2$.

(And yes, we know that the Cartesian product of sets is indeed the categorical product. It sounds like you don't doubt that part.)